# How to send email directly to user using C# in Windows 10 Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have following code

```
 EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
 email.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("xyz@live.com"));
 email.Subject = "Msg Subject ";
 email.Body = "My Msg";
 await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
```

---

showComposeNewEmailAsync() launches the email application with  above message displayed,
but I want to sent the email directly to the user without launching the email application. How can I do it?

---

As I am new to coding please explain me in details.

Comment: Using SmtpClient https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ElmoDev001 how can I use StmpClient in windows 10 apps as It says that System.Net.Mail; and System.Net.Mime; namespaces does not exists

Comment: The concept in this blog also applies to uwp http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/11/29/sending-an-email-within-a-windows-8-1-application-using-streamsocket-to-emulate-a-smtpclient.aspx

Comment: @paradox Sorry I miss the "Apps" in the title

Answer (score 2):

You have to work with [Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280234.aspx) and implement the SMTP behavior by yourself.

---

Otherwise you could also use a [SMTP client for WinRT](https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT). According to the [Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ccc0e79c-5466-42c8-aa4c-8a609ebd7af7/uwpsend-mail-from-windows-10-iot-with-vb) this should also work with UWP.

Comment: I have install NuGet package for SMTP client for WinRT. but my app does not recognized   LightBuzz.SMTP; namespace

Comment: @paradox true. I have found a workaround: Download the solution from github, build it, and use the created dll as reference in your project. Then the namespace import works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SMTP client for Windows Store](https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT) as follows:

First install this Nuget Package:

```
Install-Package lightbuzz-smtp
```

Second include namespace

```
using LightBuzz.SMTP;
```

Then you can use this code snippet to send email directly from UWP app:

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.example.com", 465, false, "SenderEmail@example.com", "YourPassword"))
{
     EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();

     emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone1@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.CC.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone2@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.Bcc.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone3@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.Subject = "Subject line of your message";
     emailMessage.Body = "This is an email sent from a UWP app!";

     await client.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
}
```