# UWP email notifications

Tags: c#, email, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Im trying to build a uwp app that will notify people by email when they have successfully created an account. This will all be connected to a database etc. but for the meantime, how do I send an email ?

Can someone show me a very basic method for sending an email. I can hardcode in the address and message for now, I just need to know how this works. The only things I can find online are how to launch the mail app in windows 10. This is not what I want. I want to be able to email people automatically through code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use this https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT

Answer (score 1):

With the built-in UWP relevant Email APIs, you cannot send email through code directly. But you could use StreamSocket to emulate a SmtpClient and send email by programming.

I saw that Sebastien Pertus has achieved this in windows 8.1 app, but I've tried his code in UWP, it worked well. You could check his blog for reference: [Sending an email within a Windows 8.1 application : using StreamSocket to emulate a SmtpClient](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2013/11/29/sending-an-email-within-a-windows-8-1-application-using-streamsocket-to-emulate-a-smtpclient/)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the compose window of the mail app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

Example taken from that Link:

```
private async Task ComposeEmail(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact recipient,
string subject, string messageBody)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body = messageBody;
    var email = recipient.Emails.FirstOrDefault<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactEmail>();
    if (email != null)
    {
        var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(email.Address);
        emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
    }

    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
}
```

If you want the app to send the email directly, you need to connect to an smtp server. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184416/6409018 for how to do that.

In short: You can use the nuget package from https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.example.com", 465, false, "SenderEmail@example.com", "YourPassword"))
{
     EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();

     emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone1@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.CC.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone2@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.Bcc.Add(new EmailRecipient("someone3@anotherdomain.com"));
     emailMessage.Subject = "Subject line of your message";
     emailMessage.Body = "This is an email sent from a UWP app!";

     await client.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
}
```